# Should Game Development - StackExchange submit an entry to the Mozilla Game On competition?

Tags: discussion

Mozilla has a [competition going for open web games](https://gaming.mozillalabs.com/) with a closing date of 1/11/11. It'd be great promotion for this community if some of us were to get together and develop something fun and light-weight using open web technologies. :-)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to find people to do that here but I don't think we're going to officially sponsor/sanction anything like that.  Unfortunately there isn't really an easy way on-site to coordinate anything like that either since the per-site chatrooms don't seem to be working yet.