# "Visit Meta" attract question link area is displaying old questions

Tags: support

Not sure if this is a bug, or just something I haven't noticed before, but I thought the set of links to questions under the "Visit Meta" sidebar on the main site always display new or most-recently updated questions from the site meta.

But when I've glanced at it today, I noticed that it was linking to questions that seemed old. So I checked, and sure enough, the questions currently displayed for me ([1](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/why-should-the-gamedev-site-exist), [2](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/professional-game-developers-and-ndas), [3](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/questions-that-are-list-of-x) and [4](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/should-game-development-stackexchange-submit-an-entry-to-the-mozilla-game-on-co)) don't appear to have any recent activity that I can see.

Is this expected behavior, perhaps because there just isn't much meta discussion so the algorithm for picking these featured questions eventually selects older ones? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe it's [sorted by magic](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?answer=164681)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the meta house ad so it displays a larger, more interesting variety of posts from meta on the main site -- it fills in this order

1. anything that has a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) on it
2. "current events" from the [weekly meta hot tab](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=week)
3. beyond that, pick at random from the 50 most recent non-negatively scored meta questions

I felt the meta house ads were getting stale and repetitive as they were...